# Finding maximum list size in a Map using Java streams

Tags: java, dictionary, java-stream

I have a map of the form `Map<String, List<Product>>`.

I'd like to find the String in this Map that has the largest associated List.

I have tried so, so many things. Most recently:

```
map.entrySet()
.stream()
.max(Comparator((String entry1, String entry2) -> Integer.compare(q4().get(entry1).size(), q4.get(entry2).size()));
```

Nothing has worked.

Answer (score 5):

If you're finding the key with the largest list, you can do this:

```
.max(Comparator.comparingInt(entry -> entry.getValue().size())).map(Entry::getKey)
```

So your code can be

```
String result = map.entrySet().stream()
                   .max(Comparator.comparingInt(entry -> entry.getValue().size()))
                   .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
                   .orElse(null); //if map is empty
```